# Tricky workflow from public page to restricted page with specific conditions

Tags: ajax, octobercms

I have a public page with a `data-request = onClaim` button.

A user can use this button whether he is logged or not

When the user "claims" this page, if certain conditions are fulfilled, the database must be updated and then a specific restricted access page have to be displayed with the new updated datas.

If conditions are not met, user stay on the public page with warning message.

To know if these conditions are met, the user must be logged in (using his account or creating new one)

note:
When the restricted page is displayed by any other way than this button. No specific data is updated

hard to explain, do my best !
Please, How to implement this workflow elegantly (or not)?

**development environment:**

- october 419
- rainlab User plugin
- debugbar 1.0.8 plugin
- sweet alert 1.1.0 plugin

i tried some tricks but according to the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), i prefer don't talk about

Comment: Sounds to me something like this:
The conditions are checked in the onClaim handler and if true, the user is redirected (you can update a partial too if you like) and warning message is shown otherwise.
You can authenticate the user in the handler too if necessary

Comment: hi dragontree, thanks for help. For checking conditions, user have to be logged already, but a non authenticate user can click the claim button. In this case we can't check conditions as long as he has not logged in.

Comment: is there a way to making display the login page in the onClaim handler then come bak to it in successfull log ?

Comment: You can always check if the user is logged and if not, redirect to the login page.
Another option would be to show the login form in a modal if you dont want to redirect

Comment: nice idea but now credit time is down :-) so i keep the idea for future.

Comment: To be able to advance in the project, I display button only for authenticated  users otherwise i asked them to authentiate before :) .... will update this question if i find a solution in future, thanks bro